# calling JD Edward business function through oracle adf

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jde

I am working on oracle adf and I want to call a JD Edward Business service through Oracle ADF.I am wandering over the internet and have not found a suitable tutorial for this functionality.Can any one please provide me with the some tutorials over this.Thanks.

Regards,
Furqan Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

You can publish Web service interfaces for JD Edwards - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14693/e1_as_web_service_provid.htm

Then you can consume those services in an ADF application through the Web service data control or through simple Java proxies that call the Web services.